# wordpress the_content parse outside the loop

Tags: wordpress, parsing, function

`the_content()` function parsed the text from the db in such a way that paragraphs for example will get `<p>` tag around them. However, when you retrieve the content outside of the loop you cannot use `the_content()`. I'm currently using `$db_object->post_content`. However, doing it this way, the text is not being parsed like with `the_content()`, so by adding `<p>`. Is just gives the plain text.

Is there a function in PHP, or does anyone know a equivalant function that parses the text the same way `the_content()` does and output the correct tags around the text.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Use

```
$content = $db_object->post_content;
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

Comment: awesome, how simple can things be. Thanks!

Comment: how do you get it to also do the iframe for oembeds?